# How to shorten questions with lengthy passages?

Tags: discussion

To improve my logical deduction and reasoning skills, I'm reading particularly longer passages, questions for which I then answer like https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33352/8712. While lengthier passages do help, the downside is their unreadability and incommodity. Unfortunately, because I struggle with the passage itself, I don't know what to omit, and so shouldn't.

Yet are there any advice or tips on how to better or simplify these kinds of questions? Do I need to post the passage itself? Can I just link to it, in the interest of brevity? I do apologise for their length.

Comment: In my opinion, you really can't shorten them. In this kind of test, you need to read the whole passage (carefully, I might add). So, to answer questions in such a test, it's almost always necessary to have the whole text. I believe that you could quote only parts you think relevant and give a link to some page on Google Book, but I'm not sure if such a link is reliable enough.

Comment: Why would you want to shorten them? In my mind, we have far more too-short questions that ought to be lengthened than too-long questions that ought to be shortened.